# Rails 3 - how to print the statement from one controller to the other

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, model, pagination, render

I have a ArticleController, in which is a statement with all items in the table Articles. The statement has also pagination with jQuery.

I would like to use this statement with pagination in an other controller for statement of items from DB table, the only different will be the other table.

How can I do that? I try in my other controller something like:

```
<%= render :template => 'articles/index'%> #here is the Articles' statement
```

But when I click on the next page of statement, I see only loading, but the data are not loaded - looks like the other pages are not loaded.

What I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:** - controllers:

### ArticlesController

```
  def index
    @articles = Article.all.per_page(8)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.js
      format.xml  { render :xml => @articles }
    end
  end
```

### articles/index.html.erb

```
        <div id="articles">
          <%= render @articles %>
        </div>
        <%= will_paginate @articles %>
```

### articles/index.js.erb

```
$('#articles').append('<%= j render(@articles) %>');
```

### articles/_article.html.erb

```
...just a printing of data...
```

The second controller - **SecondsController**:

```
  def index
    @articles = Article.all.per_page(8)
  end
```

### seconds/index.html.erb

```
<%= render :template => 'articles/index'%>
```

Comment: could you include your two controllers? It sounds like maybe you have a custom method for manipulating data? Is that what you mean for "statement"? Maybe you can move that into the application helper, but really, any kind of data manipulation should be in the model.

Comment: I added my controllers + views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started to write a comment, but it got too long.

I haven't used the ajax pagination so I am not sure how it should work. However, your code confuses me.

1. Does the pagination work on the standard ArticlesController? If even that doesn't work, then maybe you want to start from a known working example like [RailsCast #174](http://railscasts.com/episodes/174-pagination-with-ajax?view=asciicast).
2. It looks like you are rendering the index (render @articles) from within the index itself. Does that actually work? I would expect it to crash with an infinite loop or do something unexpected.
3. Maybe it doesn't matter, but I've only used will_paginate this way. Does this change anything?

   Article.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => params[:per_page])
4. Again, I don't have experience working with ajax here so I can't help you directly. However, did you get it working with standard html first and then progressively add ajax after it works? Here is one structure you could use: (I prefer explicit locals, but you can probably ignore that if you want).

**articles/index.html.erb (same for seconds/index.html.erb)**

```
...
<%= render :partial =>'articles/list', :locals => {:articles => @articles} %>
...
```

**articles/_list.html.erb:**

```
...
<%= articles.each do |article| %>
          <% render :partial =>'articles/article', :locals => {:article => article} %>
<% end %>
<%= will_paginate articles %>
...
```